# How do I remove/hide a window containing stock models in ZBrush?

Tags: 3d

I am using a trial version. I just want to know how can I get this annoying window out of the way. I tried searching the Internet, but to no avail.

I am talking about this menu/window circled in yellow below.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you would benefit from some basic Zbrush tutorials, have you tried checking the [Zbrush user guide](http://docs.pixologic.com/user-guide/)?

Answer (score 2):

*That annoying thing is called **Lightbox**, just click 'Lightbox' around the top-left corner and it will hide it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "thing in front of you" is a window showing a bunch of folders and files. Since you have "Open File" selected, the software is waiting for you to open a file. Have you tried opening one of the files, or even creating a new blank document?

I don't use zbrush, but most 3D modelling software is complex and often not very intuitive.  The software is complex because 3D design itself is a complex task. What I suggest you do is try to find and follow some beginner tutorials which show how the user interface works, before you start trying to create your own stuff.  Perhaps start by looking for beginner tutorials on the software manufacturer's website.  Another good source of tutorials is Youtube. You can find literally thousands of graphics software tutorials there.

Answer (score 0):

In specific, that's the shelf of prototypes you can choose to start sculpting with. The UI in zBrush is very customisable - look up "customise ZBrush UI" on YouTube and you will find dozens of answers.